# Read string and single out every word in the string in Win-Prolog

Tags: string, list, prolog, sentence, win-prolog

I've spend whole day on the internet and I wasn't able to find any built-in predicate in Win-Prolog that can single out every word in a String.

Example:

```
| ?- read(X).
|: 'this is a string'.
X = 'this is a string'.
```

is there any predicate I can use that will help me, single out every word of in the string?
like

```
A = this
B = is
C = a
D = string
```

or a list

```
A = [This, is, a, string]
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Win-Prolog you might use:

```
split_string(String, List):-
  string_chars(String, LChar),
  split_string(List, LWord-LWord, LChar, []).

split_string([Word|TailWords], LWord-[])--> 
     " ", 
     {string_chars(Word, LWord)}, 
     split_string(TailWords, NLWord-NLWord).
split_string(Words, Head-[Char|LWord]) --> 
     [Char], 
     {[Char] \= " "}, 
     split_string(Words, Head-LWord).
split_string([Word], LWord-[])--> 
     [], 
     { string_chars(Word, LWord)}.
```

In SWI-Prolog you can use `atomic_list_concat(List, ' ', 'this is a string').`

Comment: what does --> stand for?

Comment: It means you are writing a [definite clause grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar).